# https from Python's request module: as secure as browser https?

Tags: python, https, python-requests

From the [Python requests documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/):

```
>>> r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=('user', 'pass'))
>>> r.status_code
200
```

Can someone with access to my wireless router see the password being sent?

Comment: The encryption of HTTPS is part of the protocol.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming but  network protocols.

Comment: @njzk2 No. That's why I asked.

Comment: This isn't off-topic in my opinion - I'm asking about whether requests to https urls *from the Python requests module* are secure. I understand that https itself is secure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will be encrypted. No, you cannot see the password being sent.

Everything is vulnerable given enough time. If someone spent an inordinate amount of time to crack it, they could, but we're talking a very long time.

More information on how HTTPs works:
http://blog.hartleybrody.com/https-certificates/